# How to get sql result with only rows that has a connected relations row

Tags: prisma, prisma2

I am trying to query a database using the Prism Client and want to get back only the rows that has a foreign key in a joined table.

For example, get all users who have also created a post. I need a kind of "INNER JOIN".

I have tried something like:

```
return this.prisma.user.findMany({
    where: {
        Post: {
            some: {
                id: {
                    not: 0,
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

But the result is not the correct one.
I'm not sure how to use "none, some or every"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose I have a schema like this:

```
model User {
  id        Int      @default(autoincrement()) @id
  name      String
  posts     Post[]
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

model Post {
  id        Int      @default(autoincrement()) @id
  title     String
  user      User?    @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId    Int?
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}
```

I get the users without any posts via the following query:

```
  const usersWithoutPosts = await prisma.user.findMany({
    where: {
      posts: {
        none: {
          id: undefined,
        },
      },
    },
  })
```

Could you try this way and check?

Comment: thanks that was the answer :-)  i had to use `some: { id: undefined, },` and got the expected result.

Comment: That's how you get users without any posts, but how do you get only posts that have users?